# How do I map a char with 2 points to it's ASCII value in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin.forms, unicode, fonts

- Unicode Character 'MATHEMATICAL BOLD CAPITAL A' (U+1D400)
Hex - "\uD835\uDC00"

How do I map this to A(0041) in C#?
I'm trying to do this on Xamarin Forms.

Comment: Please [edit] to clarify what you trying to achieve (preferably with an example) and explain why basic approach like `string.Replace( "\uD835\uDC00", "A")` does not satisfy your needs.

Answer (score 0):

You can call [`string.Normalize`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.normalize?view=netcore-3.1#System_String_Normalize_System_Text_NormalizationForm_) passing either `NormalizationForm.FormKC` or `FormKD`:

```
var input = "\uD835\uDC00";
var output = input.Normalize(System.Text.NormalizationForm.FormKC) ;
Console.WriteLine(output); // "A" 
Console.WriteLine((int)output[0] == 0x41); // true
```

Comment: According to SharpLab it works as you describe. https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgHgbALANALiATgVwHYB8ACAmAjAWACgcAGInAZgAIBvIqhqnbW+x9gNwENEqBLVAAdkcKgF4qAIgA6yACIAOCgFZZcgMIkSkgNxt2DbrwD2I4aIkDzAOgByxxAFsuAGz4AvAKYAKTLmsAKp5gcHYOzm7uXHB8xqgAYuHWiU4A0uoAlFR6hAaMfgCc3qZw5hk6VAD0lVIAgpJU+gaF3t4CcBkl5gDaJAC64hIkYFC45VU1TQC+RFNAA===  So what are you doing differently?

Comment: Hmm. Seems this got a system dependency? I'm trying in a mobile device with Xamarin